# Slim Program Structure

Tags: php, slim

I wanted to add a function to my Slim application but I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know the best way to structure something like this. This is not production ready code and I obviously will not be hard coding my username and password into the script. I made this simply to illustrate the concept.

```
$options = array(
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'password'
);

$app = new Slim(array(
    'view' => new TwigView()
));

$app->config($ptions);

function authenticate($app, $username, $password) {
    if($username==$app->config('username') && $password==$app->config('password')){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) { // ... }
// ... other routes
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
    $username = $app->request()->post('username');
    $password = $app->request()->post('password');
    if(authenticate($app, $username,$password)) {
        $app->redirect('/');
    }
    $app->redirect('/login');
});

$app->run();
```

Does it make sense to have to pass `$app` to `authenticate()` or is there a better way? `authenticate()` would not be middleware, but a function called in the POST route for pressing submit on a login form.

Comment: It's hard to say as it's not visible where you actually call `authenticate`. From what it shows, why should it be wrong? What could be better than working?

Comment: I added where it is being called. I ask because I don't typically see a 'global' or 'main' object being passed around like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use registry method.. ohbtw `$app->config($ptions);` should be `$app->config($options);`

as for "registry", I use the following class:

```
<?
class Registry {
  private static $data;

  /**
  * Returns saved variable named $key
  * @param string $key
  * @return mixed
  */
    public static function get($key) {
      if(!empty(self::$data[$key])) {
        return self::$data[$key];
      }
      return null;
    }

  /**
  * Saves variable to registry with the name $key
  * @param string $key
  * @param mixed $value
  * @return boolean
  */
  public static function set($key, $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
      self::$data[$key] = $value;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
?>
```

to save use

```
Registry::set('key', $value);
```

to retrieve use

```
Registry::get('key');
```